# The name 'flashlightPos' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, object

I have these 2 errors here not sure why I also have an other class with the almost exact same structure and I dont get these two erros. I have tried setting everything to public but still nothing. I understand that this is happening because the 2 names are being defined inside an if. However as I said on an other class the problem would not appear. They have the same structure.

```
The name 'ped' does not exist in the current context
The name 'flashlightPos' does not exist in the current context
```

````
using FireCallouts.SimpleFunctions;
using Rage;
using System.Drawing;

namespace FireCallouts.Equipment
{
    internal class Flashlight
    {
        private Rage.Object light;
        private bool isActive = false;
        private Ped character;


        public Flashlight(Ped character)
        {
            this.character = character;
        }

        ~Flashlight()
        {
            IsActive = false;
        }

        public bool IsActive
        {
            get
            {
                return isActive;
            }
            set
            {
                if (value == isActive)
                    return;

                if (value)
                {
                    Ped ped = Game.LocalPlayer.Character;
                    light = new Rage.Object("ex_prop_exec_cigar_01", Vector3.Zero);
                    Vector3 flashlightPos = ped.GetOffsetPosition(ped.GetPositionOffset(ped.GetBonePosition(PedBoneId.Spine2)));
                    Game.LogTrivial("[FireCallouts] Flashlight spawned");
                }
                else
                {
                    if (light)
                    {
                        light.Delete();
                    }

                    character.Tasks.ClearSecondary();
                }

                isActive = value;
            }
        }

        public void OnActiveUpdate()
        {
            if (character.IsPlayer)
            {
                GameFiber.Yield();
                Util.DrawSpotlightWithShadow(flashlightPos, ped.GetBoneRotation(PedBoneId.Spine2).ToVector(), Color.White, 13.25f, 9.25f, 2.0f, 20f, 20.0f);
            }
        }
    }
}```
````

Comment: Where is the type `Ped` defined? The `Vector3 flashlightPos` is a local variable and can't be accessed out of it's scope. If you want to access it in the method `OnActiveUpdate` you should create a [field](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/fields) for it.

Comment: The Ped is defined from the Rage class ( using Rage;) how would it be possible to have the Vector3 flashlightPos be accessed outside of it's scope?

Comment: Are you familiar with how scope works? You're using these in `OnActiveUpdate`, but they are local to that `if` block in `IsActive`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have declared both variables in this if:

```
if (value)
{
   Ped ped = Game.LocalPlayer.Character;
   light = new Rage.Object("ex_prop_exec_cigar_01", Vector3.Zero);
   Vector3 flashlightPos = ped.GetOffsetPosition(ped.GetPositionOffset(ped.GetBonePosition(PedBoneId.Spine2)));
   Game.LogTrivial("[FireCallouts] Flashlight spawned");
}
```

outside of this if statement the variables are not defined and you can not use them.
Declare the variables outside like:

```
Ped ped = null;
Vector3 flashlightPos = null;
```

and change the if like below:

```
if (value)
{
   ped = Game.LocalPlayer.Character;
   light = new Rage.Object("ex_prop_exec_cigar_01", Vector3.Zero);
   flashlightPos = ped.GetOffsetPosition(ped.GetPositionOffset(ped.GetBonePosition(PedBoneId.Spine2)));
   Game.LogTrivial("[FireCallouts] Flashlight spawned");
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Change your scope modifier on the variable you want to access in the other class from private to internal or public.

Comment: Where does it say that OP is trying to access variables from another class? He's using a *type* from another class, but has properly declared it's `using` statement.

Comment: He says so right here: "The Ped is defined from the Rage class ( using Rage;) how would it be possible to have the Vector3 flashlightPos be accessed outside of it's scope? – Panos1221 1 hour ago"

Comment: No, you're misunderstanding. `Ped` is the type. `ped` is the name of the variable in the error message. `Ped` is accessible, `ped` clearly is not.